# AspectFill not working for Image in Xamarin.Forms.MacOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am currently working on xamarin.forms.macOS, and have stumbled upon a bug. When i try to fill my image to the given measurements, it does not do it when i deploy to macOS. In comparison it works well on iOS and Android.

```
<Image Source="image.png" 
       WidthRequest="50" 
       HeightRequest="50"
       Aspect="AspectFill" />
```

Is this a known bug and if so, is there a fix out there?

Comment: You submit bugs here: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues , and you can also search there for known bugs and fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation/bug however you want to call it :)

In fact, I have a PR which is done 3/4th but haven't been able to fix the last part.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7998

So, at the time of writing, out of the box Forms won't help you unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. And no full solution out there atm as far as i see

Comment: You might be able to pour it in a custom renderer and maybe make it work for now?

Comment: Can u specify which code exactly i should use? I see a few proposed solutions on the link

Comment: The most important bits are here in the actual PR code: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7998/files#diff-e7e02ce38379deb0c027bd4e04e17265. These are all working. So if you manage to get that in a custom renderer you should be good for now :)

Comment: Any news on this? Been waiting a long time now. Feels like a pretty fundamental thing that should be working. I have somehwat of a solution, but when i do it, i lose other functionaltiy that the Image has.

Comment: Unfortunately not. macOS is not really a priority within Forms today. Hopefully that will change with .NET MAUI. The only thing you can do is take the code that is there and make a PR of your own finishing the whole thing probably. Sorry about that :(